# How to keep chrome pdf viewer toolbar open at all times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, toolbar, pdf-viewer

Currently the toolbar in chrome's integrated pdf viewer shows itself when the user mouseovers on the `<object>` with the pdf. How can I set the toolbar open at all times? Thanks